# Embedded string syntax with colon and curly brace in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I am trying to understand syntax such as the following in PHP:

```
$query = 'LIKE {string:search}';
```

I thought that use of the curly braces required a `$` in front of the variable like this:

```
$query = 'LIKE {$search}';
```

What is the colon syntax?

Comment: why did you tag your question with variable substitution if there are no variables in your example?

Comment: This string is going to be parsed by some smart SQL templating engine. And I wish to know which one, because it's doing it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such colon syntax in PHP.